# Dynamically create new kind with all the same properties of existing model class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a universal way of versioning data for my models. I'd like to dynamically create a new backup for class `SomeModel(db.Model)` with new kind `BackupSomeModel`.

Do you have any tips on how to do this in python? Or maybe you have a general idea on how to version data in GAE?

PS: I'm trying to move away from a solution described [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691064/how-to-shallow-copy-app-engine-model-instance-to-create-new-instance).

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the model definition? What exactly are you trying to achieve? There's likely a better solution.

Comment: I need a change log for 90% of user data. It's for policy compliance, it will be rarely used for reading, and I'd like for to be stored separate from it's original kind.

Comment: So far I have a Expando model class that I copy all the data to (requires some data cleansing like eg. data and time need to be stored as datetime), but id like to for each model to have its on Backup kind, not just one Backup kind for all my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is like this:

```
class BackupSomeModel(SomeModel): pass
```

If you're keeping an audit log, though, storing serialized protocol buffers in a separate kind is probably a better approach. I would suggest having an 'AuditLog' kind, entities of which are child entities of the record they audit, containing a serialized PB of the data after each modification.

Comment: The PB based solution is interesting, I'll give it a try. I guess even if I need to show the previous versions, I still can deserialize them on the fly and the cost would be pretty much the same as pulling them out of the datastore, am I right?

Comment: @WooYek Correct. It'd be marginally higher, but I presume it's not going to be an everyday, critical path operation anyway.